# How to use a second route file under the same path in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to express and I've gone through a tutorial that had me add routes like this:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var foods = require('./routes/foods');
```

and use them like this:

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', foods);
```

I'm to the point now where I want to add another route under the `/api` path, but I'm not sure how to do this semantically. Something like this (though this doesn't work)

**server.js**

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var foods = require('./routes/foods');
var foods = require('./routes/users');
...
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', [foods, users]);
```

this should allow me to have routes like:

- `/api/food/:id`, `/api/foods` from `foods.js`
- `/api/user/:id`, `/api/users` from `users.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL has to be unique unless you use the http verbs to specify the intent.

```
var foods = require('./routes/foods');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.get('/api/foods', foods);
app.get('/api/users', users);

app.post('/api/foods', function(req, res) { /* other function */ });
```

**UPDATE**

Lets say you want to divide out your business logic in separate files, you can accomplish this with the following:

foods.js

```
module.exports = {
  getAll: function(req, res) { ... },
  getItem: function(req, res) { ... },
  addItem: function(req, res) { ... }
};
```

users.js

```
module.exports = {
  getAll: function(req, res) { ... },
  getItem: function(req, res) { ... }
};
```

server.js

```
var foods = require('./routes/foods');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.get('/api/food/:id', foods.getItem);
app.get('/api/foods',    foods.getAll);
app.post('/api/foods',   foods.addItem);

app.get('/api/user/:id', users.getItem);
app.get('/api/users',    users.getAll);
```

I personally like to have the routes listed in a file, it gives you a quick lookup for which routes you support with which verbs. notice I've created an extra function for adding new food items.

I hope this update helps

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. the `GET` and `POST` methods are stored in `foods.js` and `users.js` I'm working in `server.js` and trying to import those files with the prefix `/api`, so I can have routes like `/api/food/:id`, `/api/foods` from `foods.js` and `/api/user/:id`, `/api/users` from `users.js`

Comment: Okey, let me update my answer and show a possible solution for this

Comment: I see how this solution will work, but it seems like it would overload the `server.js` files will paths. I'd like it to have just 1 `app.use('api', routes)` statement. Your solution also splits the route path from the function. I think I'd prefer to see in the routes `app.get('/foods', function (req, res, next) {`

Comment: I normally move the route definitions to a routes.js file so I only have setup and middleware in server.js - could look like require('./routes.js')(app);

Comment: Do you keep all routes in that 1 file? I'd like a separate file for foods and users.

Comment: I only keep the url and reference to the controller in the routes file. Have a look at an open source example of mine https://github.com/RobinGulbrandsen/react-blog/blob/master/server/src/routes.js